# Salesforce integration with box.com

Tags: salesforce, box-api

I have **code** form initial request to box.com which is required to get the access token.
Then after I hit the following request to get the access token but it return this

`{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}`.

This is my request which I hit for access token from Salesforce

```
https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code='+code+'&client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXXXXX.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access token we have to made post request and when we do post request ,all parameters must be url encoded and shold be put in request.setBody() method.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the URL parameters with url encode method. This will encode your url parameters.

and also set header value with  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks your reply. I really appreciate your help, I have already tried above method but still in same situation. Please provide me more solution.